# Angularjs call Jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

I am  running the fullCalendar jquery plugin. Besides that I am running angularjs. 
Now I need to call the `refetchResources` function on that jquery plugin from angular.

I tried to use:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector(('#calendar')).fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

But it does not seem to work. 
Unfortunately I can not initiate the calendar from inside angular with using a directive.

Any suggestions how to accomplish that?

Comment: can you create fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `directive` to handle that, use it like this:

**app.js**

```
app.directive("fullCalendar", function () {
return {
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        element.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        //also you can set all options here
        //element.fullCalendar({ *** });
        //you can pass scopes in directive
    }
};
});
```

**page.html**

```
<full-calendar></full-calendar>
```

---

*How to pass attribute from html to directive?*

**app.js**

```
app.directive("fullCalendar", function () {
return {
    scope:{sample: '@'}
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        element.fullCalendar(scope.sample);
    }
};
});
```

**page.html**

```
<full-calendar sample='refetchEvents'></full-calendar>
```

> More about **[directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)**

Comment: I tried something similar but i can't figure out how to call the function afterwards.

Comment: Try to improve your question, does this page has this new question !? and what do you mean about similar!!?

Comment: got it to work! with this directive i can call it with:
angular.element(document.querySelector('#calendar')).fullCalendar('refetchResources');

Comment: Thank you so much!